# Angular JS Route Params

Tags: php, angularjs, routes, parameters

php build's links outside of this file So what im trying to do is get the url /pages/news/id to be put into /news/id and be linked but I can't seem to get the parameters to pass in

```js
// create the module and name it scotchApp    
var scotchApp = angular.module('RoutingApp', ['ngRoute']);  
  
// configure our routes    
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {  
    $routeProvider  

         // route for the news page 
        .when('/news/:id', {  
        templateUrl: 'pages/news/:id',  
        controller: 'newsController'  
    })
  
  
});  
  
//comtrollers for HH TAB  

//news
scotchApp.controller('newsController', function($scope, $routeParams) {  
    $scope.model = {
        message: $routeParams
    }
});
```